# Rust/Tauri web-driven game engine

Tags: rust, websocket, game-engine, tauri

I'm currently trying to create a game engine in rust. I have a rust `Game` module that generate a framebuffer of pixels every frame. I then display it directly to the screen in the case of the game.

However, I also want to have a game editor interface, so I have another rust project that uses the `Game` as an external module. The goal of the editor is to display the framebuffer to the screen, with an external interface to modify the game states.

For the editor, I could use tools such as Qt, ImGui, ... but I wanted to use a web-based interface for easier UI design, so I chose to use Tauri. The problem that I face is that to display the game current frame in Tauri (using React), I need to pass the Framebuffer from the `Game` module (and so the server) to the client.

To do that, I'm currently using WebSockets to pass data as a binary array of pixels from the server to the client. The problem is that this method is too slow and so I don't have enough framerate. Do you know a better way or maybe module do achieve that (still based on web-like interfaces) ?

Answer (score 0):

PubNub offers a [Rust SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/rust) that allows you to connect and integreate real-time features that power a lot of different types of games. Sending/receiving data can be [anything you'd like](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/general/messages/type) and the platform itself has extremely low latency. It's free to try and very easy to integrate.

You can also check out a [guide](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/websockets-alternatives/) to see other alternatives to WebSockets other than PubNub, in case you want to explore more options. Hope this helps!